# Errors when using ajax post request to geoserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, geoserver

I am trying to send a http post request using ajax post to geoserver. I get the following error in chrome.

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

when I use data: `--my query--` and

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

when I use data: `--my query--`.

I see that it is the error is due to the closing tag eg: `</ogc:PropertyName>`

This my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/geoserver", 
  data: '
    <wfs:GetFeature
      xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"      
      xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
      service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd"
      maxFeatures= "13" >
        <wfs:Query typeName="*:MyFeatures_df16" xmlns:feature="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ID</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>98400005701</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>                
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
        </wfs:Query>
      </wfs:GetFeature> ',
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType:"text",
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  error: function() {alert('it doesnt work')},
  success: function(result){ $("#div1").html(result);}
  });
});
});
```

Comment: @user3714840 What's wrong with spaces in a URL ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not naming your data that you are sending in your Ajax call and you are sending a string without a key. In your case I would either pass a String with a key or an Object.

- A String: 'xml=data'
- An Object: { xml: 'data'}

Source - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

try -

```
data: { xml: encodeURIComponent('
    <wfs:GetFeature
      xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"      
      xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
      service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd"
      maxFeatures= "13" >
        <wfs:Query typeName="*:MyFeatures_df16" xmlns:feature="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ID</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>98400005701</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>                
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
        </wfs:Query>
      </wfs:GetFeature> ')}
```

Comment: @aksharareddy try encoding the string before sending, then decode on the server. check the updated answer

Comment: @aksharareddy if that doesn't work either, check at the end of your code... you have an extra curly and closing bracket

Comment: look in the geoserver log (with logging turned up to debug) and you will see the received post data

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/geoserver",
    data: 'http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd" maxFeatures= "13" > ID 98400005701',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType:"text",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    error: function() {alert('it doesnt work');},
    success: function(result){ $("#div1").html(result); }
});
```

If you actually format it properly, you can see you're missing some comma's and stuff. I don't know what you're trying to do with your data, but thats probably where it's going wrong.

Comment: Its a HTTP post request why will I use commas. I feel that I get this error at </ogc:PropertyName>, due to the closing tag. In my editor, the code from this closed tag is not recognized as a script.